# Matlab - Interactive surface plot

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D matrix and I want to plot surface plot(xy - plane) for each Z - location. Now, I can plot individual surface plots for individual z-locations using `surf`. But I want to do this in an interactive way where I can adjust the z-location using a slidebar or something. Also, I want to adjust the range of `colorbar` interactively.

Is there an easy way of doing this? Is there an option for it in `matlab` or some file-exchange code that I should be aware of?

Comment: Define *easy*. There are well documented ways of creating GUI with GUIDE/App designer.

Comment: Just use GUIDE - add plot container + slider, and as a `callback` to slider which replot withe new values. The same with `colorbar` - maybe button and text field.